# Creating hex dump in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, hexdump

I want to create a hex dump of a binary file in Mac OS X.

In all apps in Mac OS, when you navigate to /Contents/Resources/, there is a file (or more) with the same name as the app.

I want to write an application in Objective-C that can read that file and convert it to some kind of a hex dump, like terminal's hexdump.

Does anybody know a way to create such a hex dump using Objective-C? (or perhaps an open source hex editor, written in objective-c?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read the file as raw data, then display the bytes however you want (for example, using a [format string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a)).

Comment: I used this solution, since this is actually all I want. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3):

[Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is embeddable, if it's an editor that you're after.